# Installing CakePHP 2.x on CentOS virtual machine

Tags: linux, cakephp

I have (finally) got a working CentOS VM with LAMP installed after following through this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6).

I am now trying to setup CakePHP on it as well. I have been following this [guide](http://tecadmin.net/install-cakephp-on-centos-redhat/) but at the end of step 2 I discovered that the contents of my cakephp folder (from running `ls -l`) are (folders are marked with `>`)

```
composer.json
>config
>contrib
LICENSE.txt
README.md
>src
>tests
VERSION.txt
```

There is no `app` folder as I was expecting...

Can anyone explain why this is and how I should be downloading/setting up CakePHP?

**Edit**

I've just realised this may be something to do with how CakePHP 3.x should be installed (composer?). I just wish to have the latest 2.x (2.6.8 I believe). Does this just mean changing the web address used in the guide to download CakePHP (the address was https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archive/master.zip)? What should it be changed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wondered in the question - it is because that article was old and so master is no longer the version I want right now.

Instead the address becomes https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/archive/2.6.zip

Since I wanted the latest 2.6.x release in particular. The last part of the address is just the major.minor version number.